# React PropType element of type

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs

From the [official](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#single-child) ReactJS docs page we can use `React.PropTypes.element` to validate a single child.

> With React.PropTypes.element you can specify that only a single child can be passed to a component as children.

**Question**

Is there something like that which also validates the child type?

**Expectation**

`React.PropTypes.elementOfType('svg').isRequired`

Comment: I've added a PR in react core to add support for elementOf in ReactPropTypes. https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/7119

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into creating a custom propType validation method? It sounds like that might be what you are looking for: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#prop-validation

Comment: thanks for that. i saw the custom validation, but I believe this is generic enough that is worth evaluating to be inside the PropType checks.

Comment: Let me know if that solution ends up working for you. I would be interested to see what the code looks like for that. Good luck!